# <video> element: Play button non functional in Chrome when using mediagroup attribute

Tags: html, video, cross-browser

The following HTML code works in Firefox but not in Chrome. In the latter, the play button in non functional.

```
<video id="mmswf50534a6a5e263" controls="controls" mediagroup="mmswf50534a6a5e263">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Whereas this code works in both browsers.

```
<video id="mmswf50534a6a5e263" controls="controls">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I have no idea why the mediagroup property affects the play button functionality.
All other control buttons work. I can even right click the video in Chrome and start it.

A Chrome bug? Tested version is: 21.0.1180.89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're generating videos in Typo3. I had the same problem and I could not find where it would append the `mediagroup`.
I solved the problem by adding this script to my base template :

```
//Remove all mediagroup attributes from video tag
window.onload = function(){
    var lstMedia = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

    for(var i = 0; i < lstMedia.length; i++) {
        if(lstMedia[i].hasAttribute("mediagroup")) {
            lstMedia[i].removeAttribute("mediagroup");
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not a clean solution, but it worked for me.
Note: I use Typo3 4.7